# How to set max_execution_time during mysqldump

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I am trying to take a backup of my database in a CI before database schema change are made and for local development.  However recently we ran into an issue where some tables are to large to dump, we get the following error:

> mysqldump: Error 3024: Query execution was interrupted, maximum
> statement execution time exceeded when dumping table `social_post` at
> row: 24988140

After investigating i found that if i modify the `max_execution_time` from 600000 (10 mins) to 0 (unlimited). The backup works, it takes approx 1 hour and 10 mins to get make a full backup. (we tried 15 minutes and even 20 minutes and it was not enough)

We don't want to permanently set this value to unlimited because of possible consequences, we'd like to just change it for the duration of the mysqldump.

Is there some way to set `max_execution_time` for mysqldump.

```
mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=login.cnf --set-gtid-purged=OFF --single-transaction --events --routines --no-create-info --no-create-db --skip-triggers --complete-insert --verbose --quick database_name > data.sql
```

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: Consider using max_execution_time of 6000000 for 100 minute tolerance.  To avoid unlimited - run forever tolerance.  Be Safe.

Comment: There is a chance you could add --set-max-execution-time=6000000 just before your --single-transaction to your command line request and be successful with extending the limit.